# Reverting or resetting a remote commit in Git?

Tags: git

I'm working on a project and using Git for version control. I did a little work on Computer A on my `develop` branch and pushed it to my remote repository which is setup as a remote branch `origin/develop`. Then I did a lot more work on the `develop` branch on Computer B, but forgot to pull the last commit made from Computer A. When I did end up fetching the latest from the `develop` branch on Computer B the graph split like this.

```
* Computer B Commit 3 [develop]
|
* Computer B Commit 2
|
* Computer B Commit 1  
|
|  * Computer A Commit [remotes/origin/develop]
|  /
*
```

At this point I don't care about the work I did on Computer A. I've already made that up that work done in the commits from Computer B. Yet if I try to run `git push origin` git is going to try to make me merge  the two branches. I don't want to merge anything. I really just want to make `remotes/origin/develop` point to the latest local `develop` branch `Computer B Commit 3`.

I'm the only person working on this project, so there's no chance anyone has pulled the last commit from Computer A. It sounds like I can just force the push by using `git push -f origin`, but a few articles I'm reading now say this would be bad if someone else had already pulled.

What's the correct way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're the only one on the project, From Computer B:

```
git push -f origin develop
```

This will overwrite all history from Computer A

It just depends on how much you care about the commit from Computer A.  I'd actually try running `git pull --rebase origin develop` on Computer B, which will try to auto merge your changes into the commits made on B with your remote commit from A, and if there are conflicts you can resolve them and then `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Couldn't I do this as well? git merge -s ours origin/develop

Comment: If you want to merge the two, then I'd use rebase instead, edited my answer.